# can't send attachment on phpMailer()

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using phpMailer to send an email. When I attached `$body` email is being send with the html as body, but the attachment is not being send. Then I removed `$body` and set some text to body (`$email->Body      = 'abcd'`) and was fine, attachment and the body text was send.
I can't use `$email->Body      = $body;` and `$email->AddAttachment("img/".$file_name);` at the same time.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$url =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $tmp=explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
      $file_ext=strtolower(end($tmp));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"img/".$file_name);

      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<?php

$body='<html><body>';
$body.='<img src="'.$escaped_url.'/img/img2.jpg" alt="" height="90" width="200" />'
.$_POST['date'].'';
$body .='<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
<tr style="background: #6699FF;">';
$body .='<td><strong>'.$_SESSION["login_user_name"].'</strong> </td>';
$body .='<td>Income (Rs) : '.$_POST['income'].'</td>';
$body .='<td>Expences (Rs) :'.$_POST['expence'].'</td>';
$body .='<td>Balance (Rs) : '.$_POST['balance'].'</td>';
$body .='</tr>
<tr style="background: #eee;">';
$body .='<td><strong>Category</strong> </td>
<td><strong>Item Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
<td><strong>Image</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr >';
$body .='<td>'.$_POST['cat'].' </td>';
$body .='<td>'.$_POST['name'].'</td>';
$body .='<td>'.$_POST['amount'].'</td>';
$body .='<td>'.$file_name.'</td>';
$body .='</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
?>
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = $_SESSION["login_email"];
$email->FromName  = $_SESSION["login_user_name"];
$email->Subject   = 'Daily Summery';
$email->Body      = $body;
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->AddAddress( 'sample@gmail.com' );
$email->AddAttachment($escaped_url."/img/".$file_name);
return $email->Send();
?>
```

File upload is working fine, I uploaded a file and  stored it in `img` folder correctly.

Comment: _Just a note:_ This row in your html body: `<img src="img/img2.jpg"...` will never display the image when someone opens the e-mail. You need to have absolute paths in html-emails. Otherwise, the paths will be relative from the users e-mail client.

Comment: Your title talks about an issue with the attachments, whereas you might be looking for a solution for an externally linked image. Please clarify. An alternate to what you are looking for can be embedding the images in the email body so no need to worry about any image being moved from the server. The only drawback is that the email size will increase.

Comment: i have updated my post with and added absolute paths for images.but same issue.i can't send attachment

Comment: You cannot use URLs as the source for AddAttachment, you must use absolute file system paths. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Start with the basics - you're not handling file uploads as the PHP docs tell you to, and it's unsafe because you're not checking the return value of `move_uploaded_file`. You could save yourself some trouble by basing your code on the `send_file_upload` example provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Use real path URL in src attribute.

```
<img src="http://example.com/img/img2.jpg" alt="" height="90" width="200" />
```

You must use like this.

Comment: i have updated my post with and added absolute paths for images.but same issue.

Comment: You are using singe quote http://prntscr.com/fqpgez, PHP variable not work inside single quore.

Comment: $body.='<img src="'.$escaped_url.'/img/img2.jpg" alt="" height="90" width="200" />'

You may use like this.